# use i18n or use date-fns function directly

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

I am replacing moment by date-fns and I have this

```
    start: moment().startOf('year').locale(this.$i18n.locale).toDate(),
    end: moment().endOf('year').locale(this.$i18n.locale).toDate(),
```

my first thought was to do this, to keep using **this.$i18n.locale**

```
    start: localYearStart(this.$i18n.locale),
    end: localYearEnd(this.$i18n.locale),
```

```
export const localYearStart = (localDate) => {
    const localTimeZone = getLocalTimeZone(localDate);
    const formattedLocalDate = format(new Date(), 'PPpp', {locale:localTimeZone, weekStartsOn:monday});

    return startOfYear(new Date(formattedLocalDate))
}
```

but if I use the following function, I get the same result

```
export const firstDayOfCurrentYear = () => {
    return startOfYear(NEW_DATE);
}
```

My concert is. Should I use the first function or go for the second one. This is my first job as a frontend junior, as  well my first and half month and my first task, so I would like to do not mess up anything. :)

Comment: Don't pass strings to the `Date` constructor unless you know they are formatted in the correct form of ISO 8601. See [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results). Also, not sure why you wouldn't use [`startOfYear`](https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/startOfYear) from date-fns.

Comment: I wanted to use startOfYear, but I am using the other function because on the project they were using i18n as an argument so, I want to keep usign the same and to do it I need to pass the string (this.$i18n.locale) to an object and get the date-fns/locale code to fomart the date. 

But I am tented to use startOfYear instead.